# Best practice to use 'ad hoc' javascript in django?

Tags: javascript, django, performance

I'd like to use a bunch of ad hoc javascript snippets, e.g. a jQuery slider which is used only in a single form. So I would not not be the best practice to insert these scripts into base.html because it would be imposing unnecessary load to users who don't need that script.

Now the question is how best to include these obscure javascripts, so that they are being called only when really needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did this in my Django sites was to include an empty `

```
 {% block extrascripts %}
 {% endblock %}
```

in the `head` tag of base.html, then use that block for any template that needed to include extra JS:

```
 {% block extrascripts %}
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ultimate-super-plugin.js" />
 <script type="text/javascript">$.ultimateSuperPlugin(...)</script>
 {% endblock %}
```

Worked like a charm. You can even include `{{ block.super }}` in your `block` if you have multiple levels of template inheritance.